# How to tell polymer dart that an attribute depends on another

Tags: data-binding, dart, dart-polymer

I have a polymer element that has two properties, `columWidth` and `columnWidthPercentage`.

Now `columnWidthPercentage` is a *getter* like this:

```dart
@observable int columnWidth = 100;
@observable double get columnWidthPercentage => 100 * totalWidth / columnWidth;
```

Is there a way to tell Polymer that `columnWidthPercentage` depends on `columnWidth` without setting up a `columnWidthChanged` function that invoke `notifyPropertyChange()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [@ComputedProperty](http://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/polymer/0.12.0/index.html#polymer/polymer.ComputedProperty). Something like the following :

```dart
@observable
int columnWidth = 100;

@ComputedProperty('compute(columnWidth)')
double get columnWidthPercentage => readValue(#columnWidthPercentage);
double compute(int width) => 100 * totalWidth / width;
```